# I want to create a input box that takes a url of a picture and when i click the button i need to dispaly the image in the same window using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

enter your url

click

function display()

{

var myimage=document.createElement("img"); myimage.src=document.getElementById("image"); document.body.appendChild(myimage); }

B/htm

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can show the image on the same window
See the code below:

```js
let submitForm = document.getElementById('submit')
submitForm.addEventListener('click', function(){
  let imageUrl = document.getElementById('getUrl').value;
  if (imageUrl) {
      document.getElementById('uploadedImage').setAttribute('src', imageUrl);
      document.getElementById('uploadedImage').style.display = 'block';
  }
});
```

```html
<label>Enter Image Url:</label>
<input type='url' id='getUrl'>
<input type='submit' id='submit'/>

<img id="uploadedImage" src="#" alt="Uploaded Image" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" style="display:none;">
```